# asp.net gridview outside button to save

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have gridview built dynamically at run-time bind to datatable, and button to save gridview data placed outside gridview

1- Create GridView

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         CreateGrid();
    }
}

      void CreateGrid()
      {
                int nTransID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["trans_id"]);
                //
                string strSQL = @"EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetTransaction] " + nTransID;
                DataTable dtData = clsGlobal.GetDataTable(strSQL);
                //
                if (ViewState["dtTransDetail"] == null) ViewState.Add("dtTransDetail", dtData);
                else ViewState["dtTransDetail"] = dtData;
                //
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dtData.Columns)
                {
                    if (dc.ColumnName.Contains("!;"))
                    {
                        TemplateField tField = new TemplateField();
                        tField.ItemTemplate = new AddTemplateToGridView(ListItemType.Item, dc.ColumnName);
    //\\ --- template contain textbox
                        tField.HeaderText = dc.ColumnName;
                        GridView1.Columns.Add(tField);
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is my template class:

```
public class AddTemplateToGridView : ITemplate
    {
        ListItemType _type;
        string _colName;

        public AddTemplateToGridView(ListItemType type, string colname)
        {
            _type = type;
            _colName = colname;
        }

        void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            switch (_type)
            {
                case ListItemType.Item:
                    TextBox text = new TextBox();
                    text.ID = "txtAmount";
                    text.DataBinding += new EventHandler(txt_DataBinding);
                    container.Controls.Add(text);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void txt_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            GridViewRow container = (GridViewRow)textBox.NamingContainer;
            object dataValue = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, _colName);
            if (dataValue != DBNull.Value)
            {
                textBox.Text = dataValue.ToString();
            }
        }  
    }
```

So i have a gridview with textboxe's all open to edit at once
The problem is, when i click on Save button "which is outside gridview" all textboxe's gone

```
protected void btnSave_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
for (int nRow = 0; nRow < GridView1.Rows.Count; nRow++)
            {
                for (int nCol = 0; nCol < GridView1.Columns.Count; nCol++)
                {
                    if (GridView1.Rows[nRow].Cells[nCol].Controls.Count == 0) continue;
//\\ --- Controls.Count always = 0
//\\ --- However each cell contain textbox
//\\ --- textbox disappear after save button clicked
                    TextBox txt = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[nRow].Cells[nCol].Controls[0];
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out exactly what you are trying to do. Is the save button supposed to save each textbox value?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not creating the GridView after a postback, and the Save button is causing a postback. You need to dynamically create the GridView on each page load. Also, I have found [this documentation on the ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) helpful on numerous occasions.

In the documentation, you will see the slightly unintuitive reason why your code isn't working as you would like - btnSave_Command is not run until after a postback and Page_Load.

Comment: Thank you for your replay
I'm trying to save all gridview data when save button clicked.
What is happening now, the postback and load event fired before button command event, if i create datagrid again on each page load the new values will gone

Comment: Move the GridView creation code to something in the page lifecycle that occurs after the button press.